# Cloning is not working

Tags: jquery, clone

```
var j=0;  
var cloneObj='<div class="ui-widget-content"><div class="form_container-'+j+'">
<div class="placeholder">Add your form fields here</div><div style="clear: both;" >   
</div></div> </div>';
```

and cloning as

```
  $('.button_class').click(function(j){
   $(cloneObj).clone(false).appendTo('body');
   j++;
   console.log(j);
 });
```

is not working any solution.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.button_class').click(function () {
    var cloneObj = '<div class="ui-widget-content"><div class="form_container-' + j + '"><div class="placeholder">Add your form fields here</div><div style="clear: both;" ></div></div> </div>';
    $(cloneObj).appendTo('body');
    j++;
    console.log(j);
});
```

You need to put cloneObj inside the click button to increment `j` and remove j from `function(j)` and you dont need to clone the object just append it

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7meGm/)

Comment: great... thanks for your responds, i would like to create a jquery drag and drop contact form, so let me know if you have any reference links.

Answer (score 1):

you don't have to use clone here

```
 $('.button_class').click(function(j){
   $(cloneObj).appendTo('body');
   j++;
   console.log(j);
 });
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.. let me know if you have any reference links for creating drag and drop contact form